# Where is the Data section in the VS Code sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to view CSVs in VS Code and apparently ExcelViewer allows that, but in the video there is a "Data" section in the sidebar that I do not currently have. Where do I need to go to show the Data section in the sidebar?

Comment: That "DATA" section you see is just the name of his workSpaceRoot and could be anything.

Comment: So right-click the file in your file explorer and select ""Open Preview" or open the file first and then select the little "Open Preview" icon in the upper right of the vscode window.

Comment: @Mark, I left- and right-clicked all over the place in the VS Code window with a file open and nowhere did I see anything that had "preview" in it anywhere. Do I maybe need to enable something in the settings or add an extension?

Comment: Right-click over the filename in the explorer bar and there is an "Open Preview" option if you have, which I assumed you did, the ExcelViewer extension installed.